# Do not show a drop down menu until there's at least one character on the select box

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-select2, select2-rails

I have been using the [select 2 jquery](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#documentation) plugin by including the "select2-rails" gem.

The only changes I did to make it work is to just initialise the plugin when the html page loads:

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $("#e2").select2();
});
</script>
```

Then I assigned the e2 value to my select_tag input in the view file:

```
<%= select_tag :skills, options_for_select(Skill.all.collect{|e| [e.name,e.id]}, @skills), {:id => 'e2', :multiple => true } %>
```

When the user clicks on the input it automatically shows a drop down list with options for the user to choose from. I thought that it will be way better if the user started typing first before the drop down list would appear (as the Chrome browser).

I checked the [documentation](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#documentation) and did not find anything that would be helpful for that. I am sure there must be something I am missing. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish that by using the option `minimumInputLength`, like this:

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#e2").select2({
        minimumInputLength: 1
    });
});
</script>
```